# Mysql syntax to get values by percentage

Tags: mysql

Im a beginner and I would like to ask how to get the 20% of the Rates Column Values *(The Mysql Syntax for this)*
.
How can I make another column using SELECT statement where the values are 20% of the Rates.

```
+-------------------+----------------------+------+
| Fullname          | position             | rate |
+-------------------+----------------------+------+
| terry, sanchez    | Web Developer        | 1500 |
| bernie, nahoma    | Web Developer        | 1500 |
| marie, viray      | Web Developer        | 1500 |
| lucy, dante       | Web Developer        | 1500 |
| benedict, cruz    | Web Developer        | 1500 |
| jhon paul, arroyo | Web Designer         | 1200 |
| lewis, abante     | Web Designer         | 1200 |
| lito, lapid       | Database Administrat | 1350 |
| jerwin, aton      | Project Manager      | 2000 |
| benjie, cruz      | Dev Ops              | 1250 |
+-------------------+----------------------+------+
```

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and produce a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select (0.2 * rate) as 20_percent_rate, rate from table
```

This should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

`select rates, (select (rates * 20)  / 100) as percentage from table`

This will give you desried result. selecting rates as the first column is totaly optional.